# Not time zone aware time in datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

How can I get the not time zone aware time? the datetime.utcnow() can give me the not time zone specific time. however, it is said to be removed in the future.

I could not find any way to do this beside using utcnow(). Is there an alternative to this? Thank you.

Comment: It's in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html): *"Deprecated since version 3.12: Use datetime.now() with UTC instead."*

Comment: Are you looking for `datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.UTC)`?

Comment: you can remove the tzinfo so that it becomes *naive*: `datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.UTC).replace(tzinfo=None)`. ***Warning***: there is a reason for the deprecation; naive datetime representing UTC can be very dangerous in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow):

The recommended way is to use `datetime.now()` with the timezone. In your case UTC.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

Note that this is explicitly a timezone aware datetime object. The very reason utcnow() got deprecated is to avoid naive datetime objects. UTC is handled as its own timezone here.